# Вывод пользователей ssh, ftp

Tags: linux, ssh, ftp, centos7

1. Как найти пользователей, которым открыт доступ по ftp, ssh?
2. Как определить дату последнего их входа?
3. Можно ли определить их последние действия в конкретной папке?

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий: у нас принято деление один вопрос - одна тема. Выберите какой-то один, а остальные задайте отдельными вопросами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответы в порядке очередности:

Первый вопрос весьма неоднозначет, в виду того, что есть достаточно большое количество ftp серверов (`vsftpd`, `tftp`...). Сами демоны не могут "ограничить" доступ к 21/22 порту (по умолчанию ftp/ssh), а вот `iptables` может, его и смотрим:

```
~# iptables-save | grep -i " 21 \| 22 " | grep -v "\#"
```

Так же можно добавить ограничения в `/etc/hosts.allow` или ограничить доступ **только** по ключам и ввести жесткий их котроль.

Предположу у вас стоят пакеты `openssh-server`  и `vsftpd`:

```
~# last; lastb; less /var/log/vsftpd.log
~# journalctl --help && journalctl -fu vsftpd sshd
```

Предположу вы знаете `$HOME` всех реальных, не системных, пользователей:

```
~# find /home -type f -name ".bash_history" -exec cat {} \;
```

**Ссылки**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406245/limit-ssh-access-to-specific-clients-by-ip-address

Comment: А если у них не bash? А если у них нет $HOME? А если /home на самом деле не так называется и не там находится? Как вы правильно заметили, вопрос слишком общий.

Comment: А если в iptables протокол прописан словами, а не номером порта? А если у нас нет iptables, и всё делается через bpfilter?

Comment: @0andriy а если бы а если не жизнь была а песня бы - пишутся скрипты, в рамках СО ответа неумесны.

Comment: @0andriy и читаете ответ а кичитесь, там много о7оворок.

Comment: Вы просто мастер угадывать!